External manipulation of the database
This is my code to connect to a database, the purpose is that when I run the program on multiple computers, the data can be recorded in the database but there is a security issue
The program simply uses an MDF file (Microsoft SQL Server database file) for
The database, which allows any user to access it
Directly to the file without authentication and to view, modify and delete data
Storyboards. This method is not recommended for production environments
Sensitive because it does not have an authentication mechanism and exposes the database
data for unauthorized access.
How can I fix this problem
HELP ME PLEASE AND THANKS
public Fonctions()
{
    string roamingFolderPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "FuelPos_Inovatio");

    // Vérifier si le dossier existe
    if (!Directory.Exists(roamingFolderPath))
    {
        // Si le dossier n'existe pas, le créer
        Directory.CreateDirectory(roamingFolderPath);
    }

    string sourcePath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Data", "Database_Inovatio.mdf");
    string destinationPath = Path.Combine(roamingFolderPath, "Database_Inovatio.mdf");

    if (!File.Exists(destinationPath))
    {
        File.Copy(sourcePath, destinationPath);
    }

     Const = $"Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename={destinationPath};Integrated Security=True";

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Const))
    {
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
        {
            command.Connection = connection;
            // Autres initialisations de la commande CMD
        }
    }
}


"but there is a security issue The program simply uses an MDF file" then don't use MDF files? Use SQL Server and/or an API to route requests through. I'm not really sure what problem you're trying to solve. Architectural problems are too broad. See [ask].

Use a proper SQL Server Express installation on a server, or Azure SQL. Whatever you do, avoid AttachDbFilename, even with LocalDB it's not necessary.
